# How to fix 'Illegal character. (line 6, file "Code")' on Googlescript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am attempting to automate emails from google sheets. However, an error pops up each time I try to save.

What do I need to adjust on line six with the error 'Illegal character. (line 6, file "Code")'

i am a beginning any help would be appreciated.

```
function sendEndOfYearEmails() {
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = spreadSheet.getDataRange();
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var text = ‘our initial sample text’;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    (function(val) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[1]; //position of email header — 1
      Var name = row[0]; // position of name header — 1
      var message = ‘Dear’ + name + ‘\n\n’ + text;
      var subject = ‘Sending emails from a Spreadsheet’;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      })(i);
   }
}
```

My desire is to achieve an automated email system to work smoothly with no errors in the script.

Comment: `‘` ----> `'` .

Comment: Use single or double quotes to designate content as a string.  The characters that you are using are not either single or double quotes.

Comment: Don't use word processors to write code that you copy and paste, since they do rich text formatting of your entered characters. You want to use a text editor, where what you type is exactly what you get

Comment: Not sure why you warpped the loop contents in a function?

Answer (score 1):

`‘’` is not valid here, use `''` to define string literal

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You're using the wrong type of quote, use `'` instead of `’`.

**Detailed answer:**

This is a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
let what = "World";
`Hello ${what}!`
```

This is a [string literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Syntax):

```
"Hello World!"
'Hello World!'
```

All three strings output the exact same thing (`Hello World!`).

The problem you're facing occurs because you're not using the correct type of single quote, you're supposed to use `'` or `"` instead of `’`.

Good luck.